# What is _recovery_source field in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I created two indexes in ElasticSearch with the exact same mappings except just one parameter where one mapping had the `dense_vector` excluded from the `_source` and the other did not:

```
"mappings": {
        "_source": {"excludes": ["title_vector"]},
        "properties": {
        ...}
```

then I indexed the same 1_000 documents into both indexes:

```
vector_in_source       1000            0     21.5mb         21.5mb
no_vector_in_source    1000            0     21.2mb         21.2mb
```

When I ran

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/index_name/_disk_usage?run_expensive_tasks=true
```

on both indexes I found out that:

1. Index with vectors in source is storing `dense_vector` as plain floats in the source as I expected
2. Index with no vectors in source does not store dense vectors **BUT** it creates a new field called `_recovery_source` with the size equal to what 1000 1024-dim vectors stored as plain floats would occupy.

So even though I explicitly excluded dense vectors from being stored in Elastic they are still stored just in a new field!

So I was wondering what this field is, can I disable it ot at least exclude dense_vectors from being stored in this field?

Answer (score 1):

[PR 85649](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/85649) explains it all about the existence of the (temporary) `_recovery_source` field and what purpose it serves, i.e. creating a synthetic source field for optimal recovery.

Long story short: you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: It looks like I have to worry about it for the time being when using `dense_vector` field type. I found this bug in ES github: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/82595